# Solve the value of a and b for a catenary (hyperbolic function question)

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I am having trouble with the following question:

> A more general equation for a catenary is $y = a \cosh(x/b)$. Find $a$ and $b$ to match the following characteristics of a hanging cable. The ends are $40 m$ apart and have a height of $y = 20 m$. The height in the middle
>   is $y = 10 m$.

I can't seem to figure it out due to the two unknowns. Could someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solve one unknown after the other. The requirement that "the height in the middle is $y=10$" gives us, since the middle is $x=0$,

$$a\cosh\left(\frac 0b\right)=10$$

You can easily find $a=10$ from that. Then use the other fact to get

$$10\cosh\left(\frac{20}b\right)=20$$

You can easily find $b$ from that: I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cable is symmetrical, from the data you have $a=10$ and $20=10\cosh(\frac{20}{b})\Rightarrow b=\frac{20}{\operatorname{arcosh}2}$